# Do Layouts become your children when you use setLayout in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, memory-management

Here's the code:

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
  public:
    MyWidget();
    ~MyWidget();
  private:
    QHBoxLayout* theLayout;
    QVBoxLayout* subLayout1;
    QVBoxLayout* subLayout2;
    //More subLayouts
}

MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
  theLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
  subLayout1 = new QVBoxLayout();
  subLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout();
  //More subLayouts

  //-------- Fill subLayouts with widgets using addWidget --------

  theLayout->addLayout(subLayout1);
  theLayout->addLayout(subLayout2);
  //add all subLayouts

  setLayout(theLayout);
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
  //Destructor with nothing in it
}
```

**Note: the layouts are members of the class.

So I know that the widgets filled in the subLayouts are now MyWidget's children (or at least that's what I thought if not please tell me) so I don't need to delete them in the destructor (Qt cleans them up right?), but are the layouts also children of MyWidget or do I need to delete these in the destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout) says the `setLayout` call will reparent the given layout. So this widget will be it's parent, so you don't need to manually delete it.

I think you should use constructors with the argument if possible. And also you don't need to store the layouts as a members if you just initialize them.